How to calculate positioning information in cesium？
Cesium has 3 longitude and latitude points p1, p2, and p3. A certain point sends a signal within the 3-point area, and the 3 points receive the signal respectively. The signal strength is between 0-1. How to get the current position of this point?
i Don't know how to start

This question may be too broad for Stack Overflow in its current form.  You'll need to research the underlying math problem without Cesium's involvement, and I'm pretty sure "how far is this point from three others" is a common math problem with examples online. Then separately, you'll need to adapt whatever solution you've found to a code implementation for Cesium.  You can ask specific questions here about narrow problems found along the way, but "how do I get started" type open-ended questions are often against the rules here for generating opinionated answers.

Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example for obtaining the points p1, p2, and p3?
